# Making slide numbers not-editable

Tags: google-slides

Would like to create a Google Slides deck (which will be used as a template), which has the page number on every slide - but the slide numbers cannot be edited on the slides per se.

If I go to the Slide Master (Theme Builder), I can add shapes to a Master (Layout) slide. When I create a new slide (in Normal mode) based on this Master slide, the shape is not editable. This does not seem to apply when I add slide numbers in the master.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The templates are meant to be editable by anyone that us them, so I think there is no way to lock/protect page numbers in the Slides.